# How to select the label name on click in nvd3 pie chart

Tags: pie-chart, nvd3.js

This is the pie chart I have created with nvd3.
[image: Pie chart]

What Im looking for:
Is that when i click any of the slices,say for example the blue one "neutral",i need to get the label value(here for the blue one it is "neutral") in the console.

And here is my code.

```
function pieChart(pieData) {
        $(".dataContentAllPie").empty();
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .color([
                     '#5EA9DD', '#008000','#ff0000','#bc5e03'
                ])
      .showLabels(true) 
      .labelThreshold(.05) 
      .labelType("percent")
      .donut(true)  
      .donutRatio(0.35) 
      ;

    d3.select("#chartSenti svg")
        .datum(pieData)
        .transition().duration(350)
        .call(chart);

    d3.selectAll('.nv-slice')
      .on('click', function(){
        console.log('hello - ', this.hasClass("nv-label")[0].textContent);
      }); 
  return chart;
});

};
```

Here is the error im getting in my console:
"this.hasClass is not a function"

Can anybody help me on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on a right way. Just pass a parameter to the event listener and get data appropriately.

```
d3.selectAll('.nv-slice')
  .on('click', function(d) {
    console.log(d.data.label);
  });
```